# Phalconphp and node.js config

Tags: node.js, express, phalcon

Is it possible to put both configs together? I know one is php and the other is js but for example, if both of them use the same database and such is there a clean way to organize them? And also what is the best file structure for an application which uses phalconphp and express.js? I hope my question is not too general as there isn't many samples out there to look at. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use some file format which will be understated by both of them. 
For example JSON.
Read config file and then do $config = json_decode($config_string) in PHP, and var config = JSON.parse(config_string) in node.js (Dont forget try {} catch in node).

You will receive same $config object.